# JMeter Function to retrieve specific value 90% of times from give values

Tags: jmeter

I have a list of values ["Sport","movies"]

I need to pass value "Sport" 90 percent of times and "movies" 10% of times to variable name result.

Is there any way/JMeter function, to get specific value X percent of times.
We have Random function but it returns random value.
Can any one help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is creating a CSV file with 9 lines of `Sport` and one line of `movies` and then read this file in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Alternatively you can use a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) with the following code:

```
def list = (1..9).collect { 'Sport' }
list.add('movies')

vars.put('result', list.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 10)))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)